# How to generate tab key even when enter key pressed in TKinter (python)?

Tags: python, validation, events, tkinter, bind

I'm trying to find out how to generate a TAB key event in tkinter/python.

I have a key binding in tkinter that works for the return key.

```
am_field_txt.bind('<Return>', next_focus)
```

Instead of calling the function (next_focus), I just want to generate a TAB event, so that instead the existing validation for the entry being used will be able to run using 'focusout' that happens when a Tab key is pressed. (I have setup the text entry with validation so that on the validate=focusout it does the checks and handles everything; but I'd like it to handle the one case where the user could press return instead of a 'focusout' condition (tab or clicking out of the text box)).
I don't really want to use validate=key because then that routine is run any time a key is pressed (plus it already is setup and working for focusout).

Is there a simple way to bind the return key for an entry, so that instead a TAB event happens?

I found documentation on the web for TCL that says this:

```
bind .w <Return> {focus [tk_focusNext %W]}
bind .w <Return> {event generate %W <Tab>}
```

For the last line is what I'd like to do - except in a format/syntax for Python & tkinter. 
I've used the tk_focusNext function but again its a different syntax for tkinter/python so I think from the second line it must mean there is a way to just generate a TAB key if a RETURN key is pressed. 
(Side not, tk_focusNext doesn't really work right either, seems to chose a different focus than the tab key does... but that's a different topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TCL code as argument in Python bind

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

e1 = tk.Entry(root)
e1.pack()
e2 = tk.Entry(root)
e2.pack()

#bind .w <Return> {event generate %W <Tab>}
e1.bind('<Return>', 'event generate %W <Tab>')
e2.bind('<Return>', 'event generate %W <Tab>')

root.mainloop()
```

---

There is also `event_generate()`

```
e2.bind('<Return>', lambda x:root.event_generate('<Tab>'))
```

Comment: I tried your event_generate() and that worked. Thank you! What does the "x:" do?

Comment: `bind` expects function which gets one argument so it can send information about `event`. I uses `x` to get this value - like `def func(x): root.event_generate('<Tab>')` - but later I don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

Arguably, the simplest way is to bind exactly what the underlying tk widget does, by asking tk for the function that is bound to the tab key and assigning it to the enter key, like so:

```
am_field_txt.bind('<Return>', root.bind_all("<Tab>"))
```

This will cause the enter key to behave exactly like the tab key, including both setting the focus and selecting the text in the widget.

If you don't want the text in the next widget to be selected, you can create your `next_focus` function to look like this instead:

```
def next_focus(event):
    event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus_set()
```

Comment: Hi I tried your first line am_field_txt.bind('<Return>', root.bind_all("<Tab>")); but that doesn't work. It doesn't act like the tab key was pressed.I guess its because tab isn't really bound to anything. The validate 'focusout' is what is using the tab event, so I guess that makes sense why it doesn't work for my code.